# Microsoft Hosted network adapter not connected to system

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking

I get this messages is shown -

> Currently, this hardware device is not connected to the computer. (Code 45)

I tried to update it and also installed driver for it but issue remains. What should I do ?

I was trying to start a hostednetwork but it should couldn't be started . Maybe because of this.

The driver also does not show option of `enable/disable`.

Answer (score 0):

Open Device Manager then right click on Microsoft Hosted network Virtual adapter and click update driver software then choose Browse my computer and next choose Let me pick from a list of drivers on my computer and select Microsoft Hosted network Virtual adapter and click next and problem will be solved with you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

Try to find your physical wifi adapter in device manager – right click – properties – driver – revert driver changes – confirm.

This will enable initial driver for which the hosted network adapter may start to work.

Explanation: For some reason, especially in Windows 10, there are some generic drivers for physical WiFi adapters which mess up the Hosted Network Feature. Because these drivers are the latest from OS point of view, system will try to push them to the computer. Even if you uninstall the physical adapter, and try to install it automatically back again via Device Manager, it will work for few seconds, then the latest messed up driver will be installed (updated). This is why you need to revert the driver in device manager.